# I am not able to understand when to use __proto__ and prototype

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

```
 let person ={
        name:"ayush",
        class:12
    }
function man(){
        
    }
```

In case of function man if I write man.**proto** it gives ƒ () { [native code] }

when I write man.prototype I am getting {constructor: ƒ}

but in case of object person if i wirte person.**proto** it gives me {constructor: ƒ, **defineGetter**: ƒ, **defineSetter**: ƒ, hasOwnProperty: ƒ, **lookupGetter**: ƒ, …}

when I write person.prototype it gives undefined

Why results varries in case of object and function?

Comment: Easy, just never use `__proto__`

Comment: You might be confused about the fundamentals. The fundamental rule is *the prototype of object `new f()` is `f.prototype`.* Does that make sense to you? If yes, then you can figure out the answers to your own questions; drawing a diagram where boxes are objects and labeled arrows are properties of the object will help.  If no, then work on understanding the fundamentals.

Comment: Once you get that fundamental rule in your head then your observations start making sense. Why is `person.prototype` undefined? Because there is no such thing as `new person()`. If `person` were a function then it would need a `.prototype` property so that `new person()`'s prototype is `person.prototype`. But `person` is not a function. Does that make sense to you? If not, can you ask a more focused question that would unblock you?

Comment: The other thing you need to know to understand what is going on is: `person` behaves as though it was a `new Object()`, so its prototype is `Object.prototype`. `man` behaves as though it was a `new Function()` so its prototype is `Function.prototype`.  That all follows from the fundamental rule.

Comment: Can you tell me any source from which I can learn prototype basics? because I am new to programming and today only I started prototype concept after completing basics of java script

Answer (score 0):

You should never use the `.__proto__` property, [it still exists for backwards compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) but is considered deprecated in favor of [`Object.getPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf).

Now to explain what you observed:

```js
let person = {
    name: "ayush",
    class: 12
}

function man() {}

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(person));
// Object.prototype because person is an instance of Object

console.log(person.prototype);
// undefined because an object has no prototype property, it's not a constructor function

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(man));
// Function.prototype

console.log(man.prototype);
// object. man.prototype is actually an empty object to be filled with
// methods for future use as a constructor function with the new operator
```